# strange behaviour when xcode evaluates variables at runtime

Tags: xcode, swift

I get the error "expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time" for the following code.
I saw other threads regarding the error with much complexer expressions then mine and it was stated, that the compiler is buggy.

Is this also true for the following simple code ?

Problem:

```
    let value1:Int = 1;
    let value2:Int = 3;

    var sql="The Number 2 is in "
    + "  between " + String(iFrom) + " and " + String(iTo) + ".";
```

but this works

```
    let value1:Int = 1;
    let value2:Int = 3;

        var sql="The Number 2 is in "
            + "  between " + String(iFrom) + " and " + String(iTo);
```

The difference is only the "." at the end of concatenation.
If its a bug:
The process SourceKitService is running at max and slowes everything down. Can compilation at runtime be disabled ?

Comment: Are you using Live Views as well? They cause a lot of recalculations if you keep them on automatic instead of manual refresh. Also the SKS is analysing the code as you go. It does a pretty poor job at times and I've noticed that pretty simple errors like forgetting a label sometimes can give really weird compilation errors that are totally unrelated.

Comment: I got that message in ridiculous contexts. It's either a compiler bug or (what I suspect) simply a design fault of the language. You need to break down the single sub-expressions. Ah: runtime is incorrect. It's compile time. And yes. there's an option where you can turn of live compilation. Helps a bit, but SKS still slows down things often.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Do you have a hint where to find that option to disable parser at compiletime ?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to answer my own question. The Solution was simply to install the newest XCode. M yold was buggy.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try that I've had some success with is to try specifically typing your `sql` variable.

`var sql: String ="The Number 2 is in "
    + "  between " + String(iFrom) + " and " + String(iTo) + ".";`

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to answer my own question. The Solution was simply to install the newest XCode. M yold was buggy.

Comment: I tried quite a few Xcode versions and even the latest 6.3 beta was having a problem.